# Newbie here with MSM issue

Tags: multi-site-manager, url, admin.php

I am working on my first EE installs: a church (firstdomain.org) site and school (seconddomain.org) site. The main site is behaving fine. On the second site, however, if I enter the index.php (which I'll take care of, later), the correct page is called. If I enter only the domain address, I get a 404 and the address bar has reverted to domain1.org/public_html/short_name.

Index.php is set as:
     $assign_to_config['site_name']  = 'short_name';
     $assign_to_config['cp_url'] = 'xxxx://seconddomain.org/admin.php';
     $assign_to_config['site_url'] = 'xxxx://seconddomain.org';

Admin.php is set as:
    $assign_to_config['site_name']  = 'short_name';
    $assign_to_config['cp_url'] = 'xxxx://seconddomain.org/admin.php';

URL to add-on site on Gen. Config. page is xxxx://seconddomain.org.

I'm a staff of one -- design (all aspects), write, maintain, and chief bottle washer, so I while I'd like to think this is a serious problem, I'm probably just overly tired or overlooking something. Your (gentle) correction would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Jo

Comment: I gave up -- not knowing any more than I do I suspect it was a web hosting issue -- and plunked down the difference for a second EE license. Ellis staff was gracious and quick in allowing my change and crediting my MSM purchase price.